# Static html css site deployed using github pages getting marked as dangerous by Chrome

Tags: deployment, github-pages

I have deployed a simple static website with an html, css, js file and an assets folder on Github pages. It worked fine when it was deployed. But after some days, it is getting blocked by browser, and giving a security error. I have attached the screenshot of the error. Can someone help me to fix it? Thanks
[Deceptive site ahead
Attackers on texnas1.github.io may trick you into doing something dangerous like installing software or revealing your personal information (for example, passwords, phone numbers, or credit cards)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mf8El.jpg)

Comment: Could you send us the GitHub repo (Like a link). Maybe in the repo you said something that google finds dangerous.

Comment: https://github.com/TexNas1/CSS-Responsive-staticWebpage.git
It's a very basic and simple one, I don't think I have included anything which is dangerous. I have tried with 2-3 more basic html projects, it still shows the same.

Comment: by any chance do you have a screenshot of what the webpage will look like if it opened?

Comment: yes, it should open the index.html, at first, it was working, it showed the page. I got this error 2-3 days after deploying. And still if we click details and click visit unsafe site, it opens the page with dangerous marked: https://texnas1.github.io/CSS-Responsive-staticWebpage/

Comment: Could you try running it on replit and share the link. I want to know if the problem is the server being used or the code.

Comment: yup, tried just now, it's working there. https://responsivewebpage.texnas.repl.co/

Comment: Hi, I got the exact same issue. Did you ever figure out what caused it?

Comment: I got this too for a doxygen generated docs on github pages. I tried google's URL Inspector and that only told me what the browser says: it's potentially dangerous. It does not even mention a specific file or otherwise narrowing down what I could be looking at. I submitted it for review, I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my "dangerous" site issue.

I had doxygen generated API reference deployed to GitHub pages. Chrome marked this URL as dangerous.

What I think actually fixed my issue was simply to enter [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console/about) and verify that I own the site.  In order to do so, you have to upload an html file (there are other options too).

After a couple minutes I was able to run a page verification. The security report then brought up one issue but there was no actionable advice on what to do.

I simply reported the site issues to Google as "resolved" without changing anything on the site. Within less than 24 hours I received an automated email telling me that the site is now corrected.

Note that you can also report these issues here but I'm not sure if it is as effective as verifying site ownership:
https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/report_error/?hl=en

What I think fixed the issue was the simple act of confirming to Google that you own the site and telling Google that you 'fixed' it.

I believe generated documentation may be a popular attack vector, given that you can just clone any repository and it will look exactly like theirs, albeit on a different URL. Then all it takes for an attacker is to compromise their documentation by making a simple (hidden) change to the docs in the cloned repository and try to direct users to that page.

Given that such a site is nearly indistinguishable from the official site I can understand that Google generally flags these as potentially dangerous, until you confirm that you own the site.

Of course, an attacker could also run the security validation but I assume this will likely fail because Google's scan likely finds the malicious code.

That's just my best guess though. ;)